# Menus with multiple item-columns javaFX 8

Tags: menu, grid, javafx, multiple-columns

My goals is to create a menu with multiple columns. I went about this by using GridPane, to which I added Labels. Then I inserted the GridPane in a PopOver. I also added action listeners to Labels So when the users click on a cell, I can do a certain action. My current implementation is based on a button. Once clicked, the PopOver will show up.

As an example, font names:
[image]

Is there a way to have this in a menu?

I tried making the MyGridPane class that extends MenuItem. It allows me to add the GridPane to the menu, but it only comes in as an ObjectID. If I want it visually, the only way I found was to

```
menuItem.setGraphic()
```

But this make the whole GridPane one item. The cells and their action listeners get ignored.

Is there a way to add a grid pane as a menu item?

Answer (score 0):

> *Is there a way to add a grid pane as a menu item?*

Yes, you can try as

```
CustomMenuItem menuItem = new CustomMenuItem(gridPane);
menuItem.setHideOnClick(false);
```

To visually disable the highlight color for that menu/menuitem, customize the related CSS selectors of menu/menuitem.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this method, but it still seems to deal with the whole gridPane as one item. it does not acknowledge the actions tried to each cell. I implemented it as a Popup for now. Works fine so far. thank though :)